# How do you apply an AlternatingItemStyle to a specific DataGrid TemplateColumn?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I've got a datagrid with 3 TemplateColumns, each containing a HeaderTemplate and an ItemTemplate. I put in a HeaderStyle, ItemStyle and AlternatingItemStyle for all 3 columns (so outside of the  tags.

I then decided I want to apply a different ItemStyle specifically to the 3rd column, which I did by adding ItemStyle within the specific TemplateColumn. This worked fine, except that the AlternatingItemStyle that I still wanted was no longer applying. I thought I could simply add another AlternatingItemStyle within the specific TemplateColumn but this wasn't supported. I tried adding it in the code behind as well through the OnDataBinding command but AlternatingItemStyle doesn't appear under the Column property. Code is below:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgErrors"
CssClass="cssErrors"
Caption="Errors"  
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
CellPadding="3"
runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <HeaderTemplate>Job Number</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Job Number") %></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <HeaderTemplate>Error</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Error") %></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <HeaderTemplate>Row Number</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Line Number") %></ItemTemplate>
         <ItemStyle CssClass="TableItemStyleRowNo" />
         </asp:TemplateColumn>
     </Columns>

     <HeaderStyle CssClass="TableHeaderStyle" />
     <ItemStyle CssClass="TableItemStyle" />
     <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="TableAlternatingItemStyle" />
 </asp:DataGrid>
```

My questions are; Firstly, how do you apply an AlternatingItemSyle to a specific TemplateColumn? Secondly, why is ItemStyle supported within a TemplateColumn but AlternatingItemStyle is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **DataGrid's** property

```
<ItemStyle CssClass="TableItemStyle" />
     <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="TableAlternatingItemStyle" />
```

are applicable to the whole Row of **Datagrid** not on individual column.

**To Achieve your requirement do following changes:**

In your aspx page add `OnItemDataBound` property as follow :

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="dgErrors"
CssClass="cssErrors"
Caption="Errors"  
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
CellPadding="3"
runat="server" 
OnItemDataBound = "dgErrors_ItemBound">
```

Add this code in your .cs page:

```
protected void dgErrors_ItemBound(Object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                e.Item.Cells[0].CssClass = "TableItemStyleRowNo";
            }
            else if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                e.Item.Cells[0].CssClass = "AlternateTableItemStyleRowNo";
            }
    }
```

Comment: That's part of the problem. I initially only wanted to apply an ItemStyle and AlternatingItemStyle to the whole datagrid. However, I now want to have all columns have those styles with the exception of 1, which I only want to alter the ItemStyle NOT the AlternatingItemStyle. So adding ItemStyle within the TemplateColumn does that, but now the AlternatingItemSytle doesn't apply.

Comment: Sorry, oddly only part of your answer showed up. I'll try your code and let you know how I get on.

Comment: This worked (though it was Cells[2]). Thanks! Seems odd you can't apply AlternatingItemStyles within the column but you can with ItemStyle.